# Is there a term for "mildly scrambled" eggs?

Tags: eggs, food-identification, scrambled-eggs

I'm of the impression that "scrambled eggs" means the eggs are completely beaten to where the yolk and white are completely blended before being cooked.

And "over easy/medium/hard" is where the yolk is *intended* to be unbroken.

Assuming that's true, is there a specific term for when the yolk is intentionally broken, but not beaten/blended with the egg white, then cooked? So there ends up being distinct areas of white and yellow in the cooked result.

E.g. in the following picture, I cracked eggs right into a frying pan with a little bit of oil, then *broke* the yolks - and let them run where they wanted, flipping the eggs over once or twice to get it cooked all over - but did not try to blend or homogenize the yolk and egg white together.

[image]

Comment: There’s a style that we always called ‘silver and gold’ growing up— you crack the eggs into the pan, and then scramble, so some of the white cooks and leaves streaks through the eggs. My grandfather wouldn’t eat regular scrambled eggs as it reminded him of powdered eggs during his time in the army during world war 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me that's a "fried egg with a broken yolk", or fried egg, flipped & broken. I make them a lot, but never thought about a name for them. They go really well in sandwiches, without turning them into a banjo*.

It doesn't qualify as 'scrambled' because it has none of the method of 'regular' scrambled, it's not broken & whisked/stirred outside the pan. It has no salt/pepper/water/milk. It's not heated gently whilst continuing to stir.

It's just a "fried egg with a broken yolk".

*For **why** a runny egg sandwich is called a banjo - see Forces.net - [Ever Wondered Why It’s Called An ‘Egg Banjo?'](https://www.forces.net/military-life/fun/ever-wondered-why-its-called-egg-banjo) [just watch the video, it's short]

For why I don't think it's "country eggs"… imnsho, anything with 'country' tagged on is because no-one knows what else to call it. Google 'country eggs' & you see a million different cheerful 'farmhousey' things you can do with eggs ;)

Answer (score 6):

I have seen these called [half-scrambled eggs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJXh7DulmNU). In the video, Kenji says they are also called "country eggs". They are not a clear enough category to deserve an entry in [Wikepedia's List of egg dishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_egg_dishes), though.

Answer (score 1):

When things are called 'country' I believe it means unrefined but not as in bad, but the way we say a 'rustic pie' meaning the crust isn't all showy and perfect/pretty but the flavor is the same. I saw Jacques Pepin make a Country style French omelette and it was a bit browned with larger curds than the 'classic French omelette that is pale with smaller curds. Its just how much a prescribed method is followed.

Answer (score -1):

These are traditionally called "**COUNTRY**" scrambled eggs (*in the United States*).  Eggs are cracked directly into the pan unadulterated (*no milk*) and allowed to cook for 15-30 seconds, and then scrambled with the spatula by chopping and folding the eggs as they continue to cook.  They result is a chunky white and yellow egg consistency.  (*This is how I prefer my scrambled eggs*).

Answer (score -2):

They are 100% unique enough of a preperation to deserve a specific term, I've been calling them "marbelled eggs" which seems to be catching on, but marbelled eggs also refers to a hard boiled, cracked &  tea soaked egg so fried marbelled eggs maybe, "lazy scramble" is similar but you keep stiring for a few more seconds